# Laptop cannot boot into Windows after RAM upgrade

Tags: laptop, memory, reboot

I own asus u31f running with Windows 7 64 bit and ram 2x2gb hynix 1333mhz ram.

Recently I've decided to upgrade my ram to 8gb and bought 2 new kingston valueram 1333mhz 4gb after specs comparison on certain website.

Unfortunately things haven't gone as smooth as I thought as my laptop stuck at launch startup repair and cannot boot beyond Windows logo. It keeps rebooting endlessly so I put back my old hynix ram and it runs back normally.

Then I refer to crucial.com and use its software to identify required specs. It appears it needs low voltage so I bought 2 4gb kingston valueram 1600mhz 1.35v. Again the same problem occurs.

I look around for solutions online and made several attempts to solve the issue. I install latest bios update (which latest release was 2011) & tried putting one ram at a time. There's no change after bios update and theres no signal appear on screen, only hard disk working after 1 at a time ram test.

Now I'm stuck with four 4gb sodimm of which none is working. I only use my old hynix to run slow laptop.

Comment: Hm, i tjhink it is too much but If 8 was too much, than why dosent get better when you try step-by-step? Did you try to reboot /change the order of devices/ over a USB flash-stick with another OS like Linux ? Try and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

One of the first things you check if your PC does not boot and you don't know why is the RAM. The following, starting with a few basic tips that are often overlooked, may not solve your problem, but it's what I'd do when dealing with an interfering RAM card:

1. Take a can of compressed air and clean the RAM slot on your motherboard. Make sure you hold the can upright so no liquid squirts from the nozzle. This will remove any dirt that might interfere with the reading process.
2. Gently wipe your RAM card contacts with a clean, lint-free cloth; especially if you see smudges. It's best to handle a RAM card by the edges and avoid touching contacts.
3. Prevent component damage by touching a bare piece of metal. Your body acts like a crude battery, storing static electricity when you rub with objects. By touching bare metal, electric charge can flow out through your fingers; the same effect you get when touching a doorknob on a cold, dry day. This electric charge can damage sensitive electronic components, hence the electrostatic-proof packaging that retailers use.
4. Verify your device can handle the added RAM and that it meets all the specs. Make sure your RAM card is compatible with 64-bit systems.
5. If you're able to access your BIOS with the new RAM card inserted, make sure it recognizes the card and shows up as functional.
6. Flush the RAM. This helps especially if a problem develops on a card that has been in use. Try restarting your PC or manual flushing using the method described [here](http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/easily-flush-the-windows-memory-cache/).
7. If you can't start your PC, enable booting from CD and try the following:

   1. Download iso file of memtest compatible with your OS from their [website](http://www.memtest86.com/download.htm) and burn it to CD.
   2. Try booting from CD with your card inserted and select the options RAM testing. You should be able to tell with that what the problem is and whether you can get the card to work or not.
   3. If you need more than one opinion or that program does not get the desired results, try the Memory Diagnostics tool from Windows itself, instructions [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/diagnosing-memory-problems-on-your-computer). There are also other third-party memory testing software, as listed [here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/tp/memorytest.htm).
8. RAM can be tricky and at the very worst, baffling. Helps to have an exact duplicate card of one that works from the same manufacturer; it's a guaranteed way to verify your PC isn't lovestruck with your card and the problem is with the other cards not with your PC.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me and I just replugged the ram and that worked. I think your situation is the same and the socket didn't fit so well.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue and nothing really worked out for my laptop, basically I got it checked and found out that the hard disk is ruined and now I have to install a new hard disk

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1123905)

Answer (score -2):

An answer given to me by a friend. If you're totally sure it's caused by static discharge, rub on both sides of the sonnector pins of the unit and then insert it again (having the battery removed ofc). it genuinely works and you wont have to buy another RAM stick

Comment: How is rubbing the connector pins supposed to magically repair a RAM module destroyed by static discharge. And where in the (5 year old!) question did you see static discharge mentioned?